# Suggested edit does not correspond to my edit

Tags: support

I noticed today that I had some rejected edits, and when looking at them, I noticed that two of them showed edits that were not the ones that I made, although they did have my name underneath it in the column to the right.

These are the suggested edits that I'm referring to:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5424997: I did not delete the sentence "I use Android 4.4 ...", yet it looks like I did according to this comparison.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5423277: The suggested edit on the right is not at all how I edited the question.

What I guess happened is that somebody else (a user or the author itself) made an edit while I was editing myself.

Did anyone notice this behaviour as well? How can this be avoided?

Comment: I added them to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first was rejected by Community, so another user edited the same time and overruled your suggested edit as Servy already explained.

The second one was rejected by reviewers. Maybe the OP or someone else edited the question in the meantime and your kind of reverted that changes. That's why you see the edits you didn't make.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, this is the result of race conditions in which multiple users try to edit the post at the same time, and whoever's edit "loses" appears to be undoing the previous edit in addition to applying its own.

You can mitigate this by avoiding performing edits on brand new posts that are more likely to have edits coming in by other users at the same time, but there's really no way to avoid it entirely.