# Why are tags added to my suggested edit that I did not suggest?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12368247) to remove a sql-server tag because the question had nothing to do with sql server. My comment was:

> Comment: nothing to do with sql server

Yet the suggestion was rejected:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.
>   (more)

OK so I get that maybe I didn't propose enough changes, but the only reason I clicked on the link was because of the `sql-server` tag which disappointed me to discover the question had nothing to do with it. I didn't really have anything to add about the question, but I knew it shouldn't have that tag.

But what really bothers me about it is that it shows I added a `phpmyadmin` tag and the `sql-server` tag isn't anywhere to be seen. I did not add this tag, and the revision history doesn't reflect that I suggested to delete the `sql-server` tag. In fact, looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37253863/revisions) shows that the `sql-server` tag was instead removed by @chris85 in revision 4.

[image]

What happened here? Why does it appear that I suggested to add a `phpmyadmin` tag? Why doesn't it show the deleted `sql-server` tag? I did this from my phone, so I'm willing to accept that I *possibly* deleted the wrong tag, but I know for sure I didn't add any tags.

Is this caused by the same mysterious "race condition" indicated in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267252/suggested-edit-does-not-correspond-to-my-edit)? I find it doubtful that SO doesn't have a better auditability system.

Secondly, the answers in [this quesiton](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267311/removing-reputation-for-rejected-edits) are a little old now, so are there currently any penalties for rejected edits? I can see there are obviously no changes to my rep, but I am curious to what other factors in my account are affected by this. For instance, I believe the rate of rejected suggested edits is displayed next to my name in review queues for future suggested edits, so this at least hurts my credibility in this instance. So there must be a way to correct this, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the order of events that happened:

1. You pressed the edit button, and started working on your edit. At this time, the post contained both [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin), so your revision keeps both of them.
2. An edit was made by a user with more than 2k rep, which removed the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) tags. The post now contains neither.
3. You submitted your edit, which was trying to remove just the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag. Since your edit was started when [phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) was part of the, post, the edit still contains it. The proposed new post contains just [phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin), which appears to be added.

So at the point when you actually submitted your edit, the post had already been modified to remove the tag you wanted to remove, as well as one other. When people review your edit, they compare it to how the post was when you *submitted* it, rather than when you *started* it.

You normally get a notification that a post has been edited since you started your edit, but it's possible that a timing issue prevented that from happening for you. Or, if you're using mobile, [you won't get the notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323134/why-are-tags-added-to-my-suggested-edit-that-i-did-not-suggest/323135#comment344725_323135).

Comment: thanks that helps, perhaps this should be another posted question, but as a follow-up do you know if the "notification that a post has been edited" appears in mobile?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Sorry, but I don't know.

Comment: I fully understand now why my deleted tag was not reflected in my revision - the posted data for my suggested edit diff'd against the question as is at that point in time shows no difference between the deleted tag since it is absent in both versions. however, this still doesn't explain why the revision shows I suggested the new tag. my posted data didn't contain this, so by your explanation, I would expect my revision history to show I suggested to *delete* the `phpmyadmin` tag since that would differ in my posted suggestion data compared to the question at that point in time.

Comment: Thanks, I see your edited answer now. Nevermind, I didn't realize he deleted both of those tags at revision 4, and then the `phpmyadmin` tag was brought back in at revision 5 by another editor.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII The live notifications do not exist on mobile. I sometimes post answers after questions have been closed when I'm typing on mobile because it doesn't notify you it's been closed either.